# Windows 8 secondary tile navigation c#

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

i'm working with secondary tiles in my app all works fine  but unfortunatly when i  start my  application from the secondary tile   it opens  the  start screen , i have searched and i know that i have to edit my App.cs  need to catch the tileActivationArguments but i don't know how to do it correctly. 
please i need your help 
thanks.

Here's my code that i use to pin

```
private async void btnpin_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //mantenmos abierta el appbar
    this.miappbar.IsSticky = true;

    //obtenemos la imagen del .json y la mostramos en la nota
    Uri logo = new Uri(pequeniaImagen);
    Uri smalllogo = new Uri(pequeniaImagen);

    //creamos el secondary tile
    SecondaryTile secondary = new SecondaryTile(logoSecondaryTileld, String.Format("{0} {1:d}",pageTitle.Text,Convert.ToDateTime(tvFecha.Text)),pageTitle.Text,logoSecondaryTileld, TileOptions.ShowNameOnLogo,logo);

    secondary.DisplayName =pageTitle.Text;//nombre de la nota

    //obtenemos el color de fondo del secondary tile
    SolidColorBrush brush= Editor.returnColorfromString(Mcolor);
    secondary.BackgroundColor = brush.Color;

    //color del texto
    secondary.ForegroundText = ForegroundText.Dark;

    bool isPinned = await secondary.RequestCreateForSelectionAsync(detalles.GetElementRect((FrameworkElement)sender), Windows.UI.Popups.Placement.Below);
    //el usuario pinieo la nota

    if (isPinned)
    {
        //ocultamos el btn pin
        btnpin.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        //mostramos el btn unpin
        btnunpin.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    this.miappbar.IsSticky = false;
}
```

and this is my App.cs code

```
if (rootFrame.Content == null)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Arguments))
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(detalles), args.Arguments);  
    else
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(GroupedItemsPage));
}
else    
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Arguments))
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(detalles), args.Arguments);
    else
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(GroupedItemsPage));
}
```

Comment: Your code is correct, I think there would be problem in `args.Arguments`, the `if` condition may not be fulfilled due to false argument.

Comment: Welcome :) I am posting my comment as answer, please accept it as answer & upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, I think there would be problem in `args.Arguments`, the `if` condition may not be fulfilled due to incorrect argument.